# Locale switching only for extension

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon

Is it possible to switch locale only for one extension but not for whole browser firefox?
if there are any exanples of extensions with extension language switchig. I mean to change the language without changing the browser locale?

Are there any examples of extensions with its own localization mechanism?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know - no, at least not using built-in mechanisms. You can change `general.useragent.locale` preference (useful for debugging), this will usually have no effect on the browser because the browser typically has only one locale installed. But it will affect all extensions, not just one. If you want locale switching in a single extension you will have to implement your own localization mechanism.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was afraid of)